# How to receieve the value from php curl transverse data?

Tags: php, curl

Now i want to transverse POST data in `a.com/a.php`  to `b.com/b.php`.suppose `a.php` has a form.

```
<form method="post" action="">
name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
email: <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
```

the following is my code php code part in `a.php`. how to receieve the transversed data in `b.com/b.php`

```
    $url = 'http://www.b.com/b.php';
    $fields = array(
    'username' => addslashes($_POST['name']),
    'email' => addslashes($_POST['email']),
     'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
 curl_close($ch);
```

how to write the form action part? is there something wrong with my code? thank you.

Comment: how to include? it's two site.(a.com  and b.com)

Answer (score 0):

before curl_close($ch),

```
url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: how to write the form action part? if i want to echo the username and email address and the ip. how to write the code? thank you